# Which source variant contains ros_control?

Tags: ros, ros-control, ros-hydro, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I would like to build Hydro from source to specifically use ros_control. What is the [variant](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0131.html#variants) that contains ros_control, or does ros_control need to built separately from source? If so how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88126/which-source-variant-contains-ros_control?/) by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1493 on 2013-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The robot variant doesn't include ros_control however:

You can download the zip for ros_control from git and include the extracted `ros_control-hydro-devel` folder with your other source folders in `~/ws_catkin/src` during the install. Catkin will pick it up during make call.

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install
```

Otherwise outside of installation, see the catkin [Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace) on building and using catkin packages in a workspace.

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2013-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0